# JavaScript Scope Chains and Prototypes

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I've been reading up on scope chains and prototypes and although I've learned quite a bit I'm still confused by the following code examples.  The first example, which was lifted from http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ works as expected; however, my attempt to rewrite it in a different form doesn't work as expected.

```
//Example 1: Code from the link - This Works As Expected
function objOne(param){
    this.PropertyOne = param;
}

function objTwo(param){
    this.PropertyTwo = param;
}

objTwo.prototype = new objOne("propertyOne");
var obj = new objTwo("propertyTwo");

alert(obj.PropertyOne);  //result: propertyOne
alert(obj.PropertyTwo);  //result: propertyTwo

//**********************************************************

//Example 2: My Attempt to Write it differently - Fails
//Problem: I thought the scope chain would work the same way for property three
var objThree = new Object();
objThree.PropertyThree = "propertyThree";

var objFour = new Object();
objFour.PropertyFour = "propertyFour";

objFour.prototype = objThree;

alert(objFour.PropertyThree);           //result: undefined - I thought the scope chain would work the same here.
alert(objFour.prototype.PropertyThree); //result: propertyThree;
alert(objFour.PropertyFour);            //result: propertyFour
```

So it is the 'undefined' for objFour.PropertyThree that puzzles me.
I'd like to know WHY this works this way.

EDITED TO ADD:
If you'd like to see an interesting illustration of the issue consider the following code.  I put this together while working through examples and reading articles on the subject.

```
//**** Function Object vs. Instance Object
function Foo(){
    this.something = "meh";
}

function ObjectsAndFunctions(){
    //this is Foo as a function object and as such function properties are available.
    alert(Foo.name);  //result: Foo
    alert(Foo.length);  //result: 0
    alert(Foo.something);  //result: undefined

    //this is Foo as an instance object so function properties are not available
    var test = new Foo();
    alert(test.name);  //result: undefined
    alert(test.length);  //result: undefined
    alert(test.something);  //result: "meh"
}
```

When Foo is exposed as a function object you have function properties available (name, length) but instance properties are not available.  When Foo is exposed as an instance object the function properties are gone and the object property (something) is available.

I doubt all of that is expressed exactly correctly; however, it does illustrate the problem (that is, my lack of understanding in the initial example) really well.

Comment: You are looking for `Object.setPrototypeOf(objFour, objThree)`. The `prototype` property is only special for functions (in the first example `objTwo` is a function). On any other object its just a normal property. Also don't mix the concepts of the scope chain with the prototype chain. They are similar but have nothing to do with each other (for the most part).

Comment: Thank you, Felix!  I had no idea what the root of the misunderstanding might be but at least you've given me a direction to investigate further.

Comment: If you do a `console.dir(theObject)` in your browser's developer tools, you can see how the structure of the objects differ.

Comment: @Christian Traina It helps, but isn't the full answer.  I think the question likely ties in several JavaScript concepts - all of which I need to understand better to get the picture.  Thanks.